# Common features on all pages of django app, but not common to project

Tags: python, django

I am writing a simple blog app in django.  Included in this, I want to make a date archive and tag cloud available on all pages of the blog app.  However this is not needed on all pages of the project.

I believe that using a context processor would make these available to all pages of the project?  If so, this seems like a bit of an overkill for what I need as on pages unrelated to the blog app there are unrequired queries going on and extra context variables.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom template tag which will display the desired component like tag cloud. See  [the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for reference:

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def tag_cloud(): 

    tags = ['foo', 'bar']         # Fetch the tag cloud data here

    return render_to_string('tag_cloud_template.html', {'tags: tags})
```

Answer (score 0):

i see 2 solution: 
1) inside a context processor, you can have the request object, so you can check if the url is in the blog apps. if you are in blog apps, you inject the desired data

2) you can make a context prosessor who inject a function who compute the desired data only at the template computing...

```
def mycontextpreprosessor(request):
    def my_func_who_work_hard():
        return range(10)

    return {"cloud",my_func_who_work_hard}
```

in this exemple, the range function will be called only if your template do

```
{{cloud}}
```

and will output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```